# Conditional grouping based on 2 values in same field

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have a data like the below

```
Number      ActivityID   UnitID          Description                     Date
1231          3456        334      Issue                     2020-12-01 23:02:44
1231          3457        334      Restarted                 2020-12-01 23:45:44
1231          3458        334      closed till 31-12-9999    2020-12-01 23:46:32
1232          4532        445      Issue                     2020-12-01 23:45:44
1232          4533        445      closed till 31-12-9999    2020-12-01 23:67:44
```

Number is the ticket number, Activity is the unique ID for all activities in a ticket number, UnitId is the number of the product, action is the description of what was done to resolve and Date.

When a ticket activity is Restarted and then  closed till 31-12-9999, then it means it was restarted in App-A.

If the ticket has only "closed till 31-12-9999" without restarted activity before it, it means that it was restarted in app-B.

My expected Result:

```
month        AppA       AppB
Dec 2020      1          1
```

I tried to get counts of them with the below query,

```
select Format(Date, 'MMMM-yyyy') as Month, sum(AppA) as AppA, sum(AppB) as AppB
from (
    select Date, Description,
        case when lower(Description) like '%31-12-9999%' then 1 else 0 end as AppB, 
        case when lower(Description) like '%Restarted%' then 1 else 0 end as AppA
    from  fct.SurveillanceAction
) a
group by Format(Date, 'MMMM-yyyy')
```

I don't know how to logically write the AppA counts (When a ticket activity is Restarted and then  closed till 31-12-9999 then 1)

The conditions are:

1. App A only had 31-12-9999 and no "restarted" message before. It should only get count of those which do not have restarted but has 31-12-9999.
2. AppB has both "31-12-9999" and restarted messsage and should only be considered if both are consecutive.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What date is the "month" based on ?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, The Date field. i.e, when the activity happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need analytical function and then conditional `group by` as follows:

```
select Format(Date, 'MMMM-yyyy') as Month, 
       count(case when AppA> 0 and AppB> 0 then 1 end) as AppA, 
       count(case when AppA> 0 and AppB = 0 then 1 end) as AppB
from (select  Date, Description,
              count(case when lower(Description) like '%31-12-9999%' then 1 end) 
                    over (partition by number) as AppB, 
              count(case when lower(Description) like '%Restarted%' then 1 end) 
                    over (partition by number) as AppA
        from  fct.SurveillanceAction)a
group by Format(Date, 'MMMM-yyyy')
```

If order of `Restarted` and `closed till 31-12-9999` is important then you can use the following query:

```
select Format(Date, 'MMMM-yyyy') as Month, 
       count(case when AppA > AppB then 1 end) as AppA, 
       count(case when AppB is null or AppA < AppB then 1 end) as AppB
from (select  Date, Action,
              max(case when lower(Description) like '%31-12-9999%' then Date end) 
                    over (partition by number) as AppB, 
              max(case when lower(Description) like '%Restarted%' then Date end) 
                    over (partition by number) as AppA
        from  fct.SurveillanceAction)a
group by Format(Date, 'MMMM-yyyy')
```

**-- Update**

If you need to count only when `Restarted` and `closed till 31-12-9999` are consecutive then use the following query:

```
select Format(Date, 'MMMM-yyyy') as Month, 
       count(case when lower(Description) like '%31-12-9999%' 
             and cnt = 0 then 1 end) as AppA, 
       count(case when lower(Description) like '%31-12-9999%' 
             and lower(lg_Description) like '%Restarted%' then 1 end) as AppB
from (select  Date, Action,
              lag(Description)  
                over (partition by number order by date) as lg_description,
              count(case when lower(Description) like '%Restarted%' then 1 end)
                over (partition by number order by date) as cnt_restarted
        from  fct.SurveillanceAction)a
group by Format(Date, 'MMMM-yyyy')
```

Comment: This is great, but I think it will also consider Restarted and 31-12-9999 , even if they aren't next to each other right? Is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: The conditions are:
1. App A only had 31-12-9999 and no "restarted" message before. It should only get count of those which do not have restarted but has 31-12-9999......                                                                      
2. AppB has both "31-12-9999" and restarted messsage and should only be considered if both are consecutive.

Comment: Ok, See the updated answer where I have added count for restarted.

Comment: Updated answer works the best! Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a ticket is closed and restarted only once (as in your sample data), then you can use two levels of aggregation:

```
select year(max_date), month(max_date),
       sum(is_restart) as A,
       sum(1 - is_restart) as B
from (select number,
             max(case when lg_description = 'Restarted' then 1 else 0 end) as is_restart,
             max(case when lg_description = 'closed till 31-12-9999' then 1 else 0 end) as is_close,
             max(date) as max_date
      from fct.SurveillanceAction sa
      group by number
     ) n
where is_close = 1
group by year(max_date), month(max_date)
order by year(max_date), month(max_date);
```

The month is associated with the maximum date of the `number`, which would always seem to be the "close" for the example data.

(This puts the year and month into separate columns; that doesn't seem like an important part of the question.)